# Multiple if Statements issue

Tags: php, if-statement, statements

I am having a problem with multiple if statements. I am using `&&` but it seems to only work for the first statement.
The code is like such:

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_id' => $post->ID );
$comment = get_comments( $args );
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 3 <= count( $comment ) && $post->post_author == $user->ID) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[button]' );
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

It basically stats that if there is less than 3 comments then show the comment form but if there is more than 3 and is the post author then show a button. The button shows but only if there are more than 3 comments. It doesn't check if it is only the post author or not, like I want it to.

Comment: Have you tried to print `count($comment)`, `$post->post_author` and `$user->ID` to make sure their values are the values you need?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing are two cases in which the button should be showed. So there have to be two ways to get into the if-block. You have to refactor your if-statement with the logical or-operator ||.

for example:

```
if($post->post_author == $user->ID || 3 <= count($comment)) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[button]' );
} else { 
    comment_form();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried testing the values, and they are correct.

Comment: Oops, it sent before I was done. The values are the correct ones and I have tried using ll instead of && but there is no change. I have also tried to make to seperate conditions but when I do that then the comment form will still show if it has already received the 3 doing it that way.

Comment: comment_form() is executed when user->ID is not post_author or count($comment) is > 3. If that's not what you want, please tell again, when comment_form() should be executed or when not. OP is a bit misleading I think.

Comment: That is what I would like for it to do. It just was not working. I have tried playing with it the same exact way several different ways. I couldn't wrap my head around it. I just figure out the solution. I had to use 'global $post,$current_user;' and add a elseif condition. I'll post the full code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the code like so to get it to work.

```html
global $post,$current_user;
$args = array( 'post_id' => $post->ID );
$comment = get_comments( $args );
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[button]' );
} elseif ( 3 <= count( $comment ) ) {
// blank
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```